# Screen flickers every morning at 4 AM

Tags: windows-7, display, windows-10

I'm experiencing a weird issue with my PC. Every morning at exactly 4 AM my screen will go black for a few seconds, then come back and again turn black for another few seconds until resuming normal operation.

While this is not much of an issue in itself (I'm rarely up at 4 AM and the flicker only lasts for a few seconds), I'm curious what could cause such behaviour.

Theres nothing in Event Viewer logs happening at 4 AM. I don't know where else to look.

Some specs:

- Windows 10 (Updated from Windows 7, the problem persists)
- NVidia GTX 760
- Core i5-4670K
- Only connected devices are keyboard (Microsoft) and mouse (Roccat)
- AVG Free antivirus

Any ideas where I could even start looking for the cause? Where can I see if there's something scheduled to run every night? What other software could be doing this?

Comment: ..... "While this is not much of an issue in itself (I'm rarely up at 4 AM and the flicker only lasts for a few seconds),".....   How do you know it's every morning if there's no trace as you say? As it is, we can only guess. Vote to close.

Comment: You might try Task Scheduler and see if anything runs at that time.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: I'm rarely up but still over the years I've witnessed it dozens of times. Every time I'm logged in at 4 AM, the screen will flicker. Exactly 4 AM, going black two times. Strange. I'm trying to comb the Task Scheduler but not finding anything running at that time..